# Posting codeigniter form with modal as partial view not passing correct variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-3

I am trying to submit a form via a simple modal with a yes or no button. However, when I click the button in the view the event_id is not updating and only passes the first event_id. I am assuming I need to somehow update the event_id that is passed to the modal; as it appears to already be loaded. How do I go about this? I was thinking maybe a onclick function that sets eventId but, I am very new to coding and don't know how to go about. Hopefully this makes sense.

Here is my controller:

```
function skatersuccess(){
    if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">You must be an admin to view this page</div>');
        redirect('/');
    }

    $event_id = $this->input->post('event_id');
    $user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');

    $user_data = array(
            'id'    => 'null',
            'user_id' => $user_id,
            'event_id' => $event_id,
            'is_paid' => 1
        );

    $this->user_event_model->registerskater($user_data);
    redirect('/dashboard/','refresh');
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
public function registerskater($user_data) {
        $this->load->database('hockey');
        $this->db->insert('users_events', $user_data);
    }
```

Here is the mainview button code(this loads the popup modal:

```
<?php if (($e->user_registered == 1)) : ?>
  <?php $this->load->view('admin/partial/skater_cancel', $e) ?>
  <?php elseif (($e->capacity == $e->registered)): ?>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">FULL</button>
  <?php else: ?>
  <?php $this->load->view('admin/partial/skater', $e) ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

and here is the popup modal view:

```
    <form action="dashboard/skatersuccess" name="" id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-title="add_skater" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_skater" >SIGN UP AS SKATER</button>

    <!--Pop Up Dialog-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">    </span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Signup for Game?</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span>Are you sure you want to sign up for game?</div>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer ">



    <button type="button" id="btnYES" href="#" name="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Yes</button>

    <input id="event_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" placeholder="event_id">
        <input id="user_id" type="hidden" class="form-control" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_id'); ?>" placeholder="user_id">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> No</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content --> 
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Since PHP is loaded only once it is not possible to get the session data via javascript. if you want to edit the value of an input on button click this is easy to do not with the session value: `$('button.btn').on('click', function() { $('#event_id').val(myvalue); });`

Comment: Sorry, i'm not following, could you show an example? Will session data pass to a partial view?

Answer (score 0):

I got it with this,

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".add_skater", function (e) {

e.preventDefault();

var _self = $(this);

var myEventId = _self.data('id');
$("#EventId").val(myEventId);

$(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
</script>
```